# How make subtraction with shift in excel?

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I would like to make a subtraction with date_time in excel but with a shift of two rows, I don't know the excel function

```
2020-11-26 20:00:00
2020-11-26 21:00:00
2020-11-26 22:00:00
2020-11-26 23:30:00
```

Explanation:

```
(2020-11-26 21:00:00) - (2020-11-26 20:00:00)
(2020-11-26 23:30:00) - (2020-11-26 22:00:00)
```

The result must be:

```
01:00:00
01:30:00
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I can assume your list of dates starts in cell `A1` then this formula works:

```
=OFFSET($A$1,2*(ROW()-1)+1,0)-OFFSET($A$1,2*(ROW()-1),0)
```